# No route matches {:action=>"show", } missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While trying to access /students Im getting this error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"students", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

File with error is app/views/students/_student.haml

```
%tr
%td= student.first_name
%td= student.last_name
%td
= link_to student_path(student), { title: t('shared.show') } do
  %button.btn.btn-default
    = fa_icon "search"
```

Model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :subject_item_notes, dependent: :destroy
validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

Action: (I also have update and destroy actions)

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
expose(:student, attributes: :student_params)
expose(:student_subject_items) { student.subject_items }

def create
if student.save
redirect_to student_path(student), notice: I18n.t('shared.created', resource: 'Student')
else
render :new
end
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
resources :students do
get :subjects end
resources :teachers do
get :subjects end
resources :reports do
get :subjects end
resources :visitors
resources :subject_items
root to:  'students#index' end
```

Is there a problem with my routes (route for show action) or I need additional action ? My other controller works and I guess its almost the same. Is this error becouse of setting students#index as root route ?

index.html.haml

```
= link_to t('shared.add_new_item'), new_student_path, class: 'btn btn-default'
%table.table.table-condensed
%thead
%tr
%th= t('student.columns.first_name')
%th= t('student.columns.last_name')
%th= t('shared.actions')
%tbody
= render student
```

Comment: Your student object has no id. BTW, what was the name of the gem which was adding this `expose` interface?

Comment: decent-exposure Like this: expose(:student, attributes: :student_params, :student_id) ?

Comment: Thx, was trying to find this recently. Now on how to fix it - please show your index view, especially the loop in which you render that partial.

Comment: In index you are trying to render one student, you should iterate students...

Comment: any tip how I need to change index file ? Done. Thx.

Comment: Use `students.each` to iterate through the list. https://teamtreehouse.com/library/how-to-use-the-each-method-in-ruby-on-rails